# Showing the latest value in a line chart with Aspose.Words Net

Tags: aspose.words

Following the [Working with Charts](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/working-with-charts/#how-to-work-with-single-chartdatapoint-of-a-chartseries) tutorial, I've been trying to show the latest value in a chart line series for the current or previous year. I receive two matrices as shown below in which their Count property is always either between one and two. As said, the matrix of DateTime may have one or two lists having each at least 365 days. The second matrix has the corresponding double for each day.

`List<List<DateTime>> AxisX, List<List<double>> AxisY, List<string> seriesName`

```
shape = (Shape)doc.Range.Bookmarks[bookmarkName.GetDescription()].BookmarkStart.NextSibling;
Chart chart = shape.Chart;
chart.Legend.Position = LegendPosition.TopRight;
chart.Legend.Overlay = true;
chart.Series.Clear();
chart.AxisX.CategoryType = AxisCategoryType.Time;
chart.AxisX.BaseTimeUnit = AxisTimeUnit.Days;
chart.AxisX.MajorUnitScale = AxisTimeUnit.Months;
chart.AxisX.MajorUnit = 1;
chart.AxisX.TickLabelAlignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;

if (eixoX.Any() && eixoX.ElementAt(0).Any())
{
      chart.AxisX.Scaling.Maximum = new AxisBound(eixoX.ElementAt(0).Last());
      chart.AxisX.Scaling.Minimum = new AxisBound(eixoX.ElementAt(0).First());
}
```

Until now I was able to show the latest value in the chart if the AxisY[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyycR.png)] has **continuous** values like this:

```
            chart.AxisX.NumberFormat.FormatCode = "mmm";
            eixosY.ForEach((eixoY, i) =>
            {
                if (eixoX.ElementAt(i).Any() && eixoY.Any())
                {
                    var x = eixoX.ElementAt(i).ToArray();
                    var y = eixoY.ToArray();
                    var s = nomeSeries.ElementAt(i);
                    chart.Series.Add(s, x, y);
                }
            });
```

And then I iterate through AxisY[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyycR.png)] and get the latest value as follows:

```
                var array = chart.Series.Count - 1;
                var serie = eixosY[array].ToArray();
                var last = 0;



                for (int i = serie.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (Double.IsNaN(serie[i])) continue;
                    last = i;
                    break;
                }

                var labels = chart.Series[array].DataLabels;
                ChartDataLabel l = labels.Add(last);
                l.ShowValue = true;
```

That produces the following result as expected:

[image]

Now the problem. When AxisY[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyycR.png)] is non-continuous I can't get the same result. Instead, I got something like this:
[image]
I just can't show the tuple X and Y value as in the previous image. I wanted the chart to show the value 57.1 since it is the latest value for the data in AxisY[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyycR.png)]:

```
-       y   {double[366]}   double[]
        [0] 29.9338 double
        [1] 29.5862 double
        [2] NaN double
        [3] NaN double
        [4] NaN double
        [5] NaN double
        [6] NaN double
        [7] NaN double
        [8] NaN double
        [9] NaN double
        [10]    NaN double
        [11]    NaN double
        [12]    NaN double
        [13]    NaN double
        [14]    NaN double
        [15]    NaN double
        [16]    NaN double
        [17]    NaN double
        [18]    NaN double
        [19]    NaN double
        [20]    NaN double
        [21]    NaN double
        [22]    NaN double
        [23]    NaN double
        [24]    NaN double
        [25]    NaN double
        [26]    NaN double
        [27]    NaN double
        [28]    NaN double
        [29]    NaN double
        [30]    NaN double
        [31]    NaN double
        [32]    NaN double
        [33]    NaN double
        [34]    23.282  double
        [35]    NaN double
        [36]    NaN double
        [37]    NaN double
        .
        . 
        .
        [147]   NaN double
        [148]   16.5327 double
        .
        .
        .       
        .
        [254]   57.1    double
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you do not need to use [DataLabels.Add](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.drawing.charts/chartdatalabelcollection/methods/add) method, since it is obsolete. It is enough to set [ChartSeries.HasDataLabels](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.drawing.charts/chartseries/properties/hasdatalabels) property to `true` and then access the required `DataLabel` by index. I created a simple code example where X values has NaN values in the middle and at the end. The data label is displayed correctly as seen on the screenshot.

```cs
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

Shape shape = builder.InsertChart(ChartType.Line, 500, 300);
Chart chart = shape.Chart;

chart.Series.Clear();

double[] xValues = new double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
double[] yValues = new double[] { 1, 2, double.NaN, double.NaN, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, double.NaN };

ChartSeries series = chart.Series.Add("Test", xValues, yValues);

// Determine the last no NaN value index.
int last = yValues.Length - 1;
while (double.IsNaN(yValues[last]) && last > 0)
    last--;

// Enable data labels.
series.HasDataLabels = true;
// Display the value of the last not NaN value.
series.DataLabels[last].ShowValue = true;

doc.Save(@"C:\Temp\out.docx");
```

[image]